# Libgdx simultaneous key presses

Tags: java, input, keyboard, libgdx

I started developing a game using libgdx. It is a top-down 2d game, where you can control your character with w,a,s,d and rotate him with q and e. In the game i handle multiple key presses by setting a boolean value (wPressed = true/false...). But i noticed, that when i press "W" and "D" to go right up, while rotating by pressing "E" i can't shoot by pressing "SPACE". So it seems, that i can't handle more then 3 Inputs. My question now: Is that a Java, libgdx or Hardware dependent thing? My Google research showed me that it has to do with the keyboard buffer, but i am not sure if also Java or libgdx adds some limitations. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is maybe a case of your keyboard. Not every keyboard handles more than 3-4 keydowns at the same time.(called Ghosting) Even depending on the keys you are pressing. e.g. some keyboards handle at the lefthand more than 4 keys but on the right hand just one.

Test the combination here if it works: [Keyboard Ghosting Demonstration](http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/keyboardghostingdemo.mspx)

If not it's not your inputhandler it's simply the hardware else its the inputhandler and you need show us the code.

Comment: I know that it is not how implemented the inputHandling (: I just wanted to know if it is only a hardware thing or if Java itself Limits the keys. Thanks for that fast answer! I will try the Keyboard Ghosting Demonstration and if it is realy my implementation i will ask again (but i really don't think so :P)

Comment: You're wellcome. Had an simmelar issue with that.